# "Yet at the end of the day, Mr. Guaidó fell short of the prize he sought" meaning

Tags: sentence-meaning

Does the sentence :

> Yet at the end of the day, Mr. Guaidó fell short of the prize he sought.

mean that :

> Even though a whole day went by and now its the evening, Mr. Guaidó failed to reach his goal.

?

Comment: As in many languages, in English a "day" can be metaphorically applied to any specified length of time, for example, *"At the end of the day we are all of us older but not necessarily wiser"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *could* mean that, yes. However, "At the end of the day" is also a saying that could mean at the end of any given period of time in this context.

For example:

> He fought hard during a two-year-long campaign to win the election. Yet at the end of the day, he fell short of the prize he sought.

Conceptually, there are two different ways to interpret this usage:

1. The day being referred to is the last day of the time period.
2. The time period is being condensed into a single day as a metaphor.

To help understand the second interpretation, there is a [well-known ancient riddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx#Riddle_of_the_Sphinx) which in English reads:

> It walks on four legs in the morning, two legs at noon, and three legs in the evening. What is it?

The answer to the riddle is a human. Morning refers to early age, noon to middle age, and evening to senior age. Babies crawl on their hands and feet, teens and adults walk on two feet, and seniors are known to use canes to walk around (and hence "three legs").

The riddle condenses the entire lifetime of a person into a single day to serve as a metaphor.

Comment: If it's the second meaning that's being used, then "However, at the end, Mr. Guaidó failed to reach his goal" would be a better interpretation, wouldn't it ?

Comment: @Norbert Yes, that's right.

Answer (score -1):

The phrase "at the end of the day" is one of those English cliches. It's often over used and misapplied. It means something like "at the end of some sequence" or "after everything was settled" or "at the conclusion of some contest" or various similar things. It isn't usually referring to a time of day.

Comment: It's a *common* saying, but I don't know if I'd called it "cliche" or "over-used".

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=at%20the%20end%20of%20the%20day

Comment: -1  I wouldn't recommend using the urban dictionary to support an argument, since it's based entirely on anecdote, hearsay, and conjecture.  It's not bad to add possible alternate meanings, or to help define slang terms, but it's frequently, laughably parochial, out-of-date, and just plain wrong.

Comment: @Andrew So there is enough "anecdote, hearsay, and conjecture" about the phrase to produce an UD entry. And that's not evidence it's cliche. OK.